# Copy a range of values into an external .txt line VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy, copy-paste

I have an Excel worksheet and I need to copy a range of values into an external `.txt` file at a given line. (E.g. copy the values of cells A1:A7, and paste them in line 100 of a pre-existing `.txt` file.  I was able to select the range of values, however I can not paste into a specific line. Any ideas?

Comment: Break your work into problem parts, and you see that your next task(based in info described) is to locate a line in a text file. Can you parse a text file by using vbCr as a marker? Then after the 100th such vbCr, the previous textstring is the one you want to overwrite with your copied value. You have not shown any code where you get into a text file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This is a hack:

Public Const FPath = "C:\Temp\YourFile.txt"

Sub test()
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim txtFile As Scripting.TextStream

Dim val As String
Dim valArr() As Variant, v As Variant
valArr = Sheet1.Range("A1:A7").Value2

Dim count As Long
For count = LBound(valArr) To UBound(valArr)
    'choose your delimiter, I used space
    val = val & IIf(count = LBound(valArr), "", " ") & valArr(count, 1)
Next count

Set txtFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FPath, ForReading, False)

Dim txtArr() As String
txtArr = Split(txtFile.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
txtFile.Close

If UBound(txtArr) >= 4 Then 'I am using 5 instead of 100 - change as necessary
    txtArr(4) = val
    're-write file
    Set txtFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FPath, ForWriting, False)
    txtFile.Write Join(txtArr, vbCrLf)
    txtFile.Close
Else
    'append to file if it has less then 5 lines
    Set txtFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FPath, ForAppending, False)
    txtFile.Write val
    txtFile.Close
End If

Set txtFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, that works fine for me. However I am now trying to run an _exe_ 
this is the code that I have written :
Dim source As String
source = "C:\test\_run\convtecg2.exe"
Shell (source)

The problem that I experience is that the program should give as output a file called "geo" which is not created (looks like the program never start, since it starts and immediately shut down). Any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea what that .exe will do, and this would be outside of the question scope. Sorry... If my answer worked for you, then please consider to mark it as accepted answer. You discuss the .exe in a new question. somewhat maybe can help with the .exe issues